# PHP(5.4系)で任意の変数の値がある時点以降に参照、代入されたかをチェックする方法はありますでしょうか？

Tags: php

やりたいことは、

```
$hoge = 5;
```

などとされている変数があって、それ以降、参照も代入もされていない場合、不要なのでそもそも消すということがやりたいのです。
実際には、クラスのメンバ変数で、どこかのメソッドで参照してるか、変更してるかというのも加味して調べたいし、
これが配列の場合に、

```
$hoge['a'] = 5;
$hoge['b'] = 5;
$hoge['c'] = 5;
```

とあある場合、

```
$hoge['b']
```

だけ、以降参照も変更もされていない
みたいなことを知りたいのです。

すごく基本的なことで、それはこうするとすぐわかるよ
みたいなことなのか、
それとも、そんな都合の良いことはできない
ということなのかもわからないのですが、アドバイスいただければ助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あくまでデバッグ上でやるだけであればzend内部で持っている参照カウント`refcount`を見てやればいいかと思います。
(確かPHP5～だったと思う)
参照で引き渡した後の`refcount`も増加する点に注意してください。
実装で行いたいのであればBLUEPIXYさんの言うとおりないです。

```
function debug_zval($n){
    $zval_container = "";
    ob_start();
    debug_zval_dump($n);
    $zval_container = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $zval_container;
}

echo debug_zval($hoge['b']);
```

[参考：参照カウントについて](http://php.net/manual/ja/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)
[参考：zendの値をダンプする](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.debug-zval-dump.php)

Comment: 意図はデバッグ上で無駄なコードを削りたいということですので、私が知りたかったことをバッチリお教えいただいた感じです！！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

本家に似たような[質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940369/how-to-check-for-unused-variables-functions-in-class)がありました。

基本プログラム中から（それらをチェックするようなコードを実装(参照カウントを持つような実装)しないで）チェックする方法はないと思います。
なので、チェックするにはソース自体をチェックする必要があって、リンク先によるといくつかそういうチェックをするツールがある(多分チェック先で挙げられている以外にもあると思う)ようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！デバッガなどを使って…みたいな感じのことのようですね。参考になりました！